# QT - Write and Read using QSerialPort (ASCII command)

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port, ascii

I'm making a program through QT. It requires to communicate between PC and serial port.

So I connect the serialport, but I don't know how to write and read.
The document says **"interface(serialport) responds to ASCII commands received over the USB acting as a virtual serial port."**

I think I have to use QIODevice::Write and read but I don't know how to utilize them and interpret the response. Can you do me a favor?
I attach my codes and some part of the document. below

**motorport.h**

```
#ifndef MOTORPORT_H
#define MOTORPORT_H

#include <QSerialPort>


class MotorPort : public QSerialPort
{
    Q_OBJECT
~~~~~
```

**motorport.cpp**

```
void MotorPort::openMotorPort(const QString &portName)
{
    setPortName(portName);
    setBaudRate(defaultBaudRate);
    setDataBits(defaultDataBits);
    setStopBits(defaultStopBits);
    setParity(defaultParity);
    open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);

}
```

**mainwindow.h**

```
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    MotorPort *rls;

//mainwindow.cpp
rls->openMotorPort("COM5");  //success to connect serialport
rls->write("?");  //try to send ASCII command '?' but I don't know....
QByteArray data = rls->readAll();  //
```

[Reference Screenshot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7S0dG.png)

Comment: What is your exact question? Please write your question clearly

Answer (score 0):

```
QObject::connect(serial,&QSerialPort::readyRead,this,&MainWindow::ReadData);

//read

void MainWindow::ReadData()
{
QByteArray buf;

buf=serial->readAll();
if(!buf.isEmpty())
{
    QString str = buf;
    ui->txtRead->appendPlainText(str);
}
buf.clear();
}


// write
{

serial->write(ui->txtWrite->toPlainText().toLatin1());

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this link can help you : https://forum.qt.io/topic/63856/read-and-write-in-serial-port

> ```
> #include "myserialport.h"
> #include <QtSerialPort/QSerialPort>
> #include <QMessageBox>
> #include <QObject>
>
> MySerialPort::MySerialPort()
> {
>    serial = new QSerialPort(this);
>    connect(serial, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readData()));
>    //openSerialPort();
> }
>
>
> void MySerialPort::openSerialPort()
> {
>    serial->setPortName("COM3");
>    serial->setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud9600);
>    serial->setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
>    serial->setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
>    serial->setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
>    serial->setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);
>    if (serial->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)) {
>
>        showStatusMessage("Connectedd");
>
>    } else {
>
>        showStatusMessage(tr("Open error"));
>    }
> }
>
> void MySerialPort::closeSerialPort()
> {
>    if (serial->isOpen())
>        serial->close();
>
>    showStatusMessage(tr("Disconnected"));
> }
>
> void MySerialPort::writeData(const QByteArray &data)
> {
>    serial->write(data);
> }
>
> void MySerialPort::readData()
> {
>   QByteArray data = serial->readAll();
>
>   qDebug() << data;
>
> }
>
> void MySerialPort::handleError(QSerialPort::SerialPortError error)
> {
>    if (error == QSerialPort::ResourceError) {
>        closeSerialPort();
>    }
> }
>
>
> void MySerialPort::showStatusMessage(const QString &message)
> {
>    qDebug() << message;
> }
> ```

<sub>**Note** The code above is a verbatim copy from the aforementioned link.</sub>